# notepad++ перенос строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью notepad ++ добавлять новую строку для каждого имени

Текст вида:

```
979 alex    john
980 henrey  peter
981 clark   oswald
...
```

Таких строк 2000 штук. С помощью регулярки [0-9] удаляю все цифры (они мне не нужны). Пользовался \r\n, нужно доколдовать до Готового шаблона вида:

```
alex
john
henrey
peter
clark
oswald
```

Comment: Попробуйте найти `^\d+\h+(\S+).*` и заменить на `$1`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @WiktorStribiżew , но, к сожалению, не получается

Comment: `^\d+\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)$` -> `$1\r\n$2` - так надо было. `\s` находит знаки перевода строки, `\h` - нет. Я не обратил внимание на то, что значение 3-го столбца тоже должно присутствовать в результате.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего исходного текст вида  `979 alex    john`
сделайте замену

```
^\d+\s+([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)$
```

на

```
$1\n$2
```

получите искомый рузльтат

Comment: Хм, получилось. Но вот чего я действительно не понимаю, это при экспорте (ctrl+c) у меня имена идут слитно по два: alexjohn, henreypeter и т.д

Comment: @aloe тогда на `$1\r\n$2`

Comment: отлично, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Замените пробелы на перенос строки  на `\r` (*Курсор в начало первой строки, Направление - вниз, Режим поиска - расширенный*)
2. Удалите с регуляркой (замените) строки с цифрами `^[0-9\s]*$` на пустое значение  (*Курсор в начало первой строки, Направление - вниз, Режим поиска - регулярные выражения*)

Comment: спасибо, уже решено!